# Vitest + MSW - Runtime request handler is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-query, msw, vitest, react-hooks-testing-library

I'm trying to migrate the test framework of my app from Jest to Vitest (for multiple reasons) and I encounter an issue.

With Jest, I was using `runtime request handlers` at multiple places of my app to control that I have the correct behavior/output in my component regarding the response of the API call.

It was working well! But now, with Vitest, I can't achieve the same behavior.

I'm doing the same thing as before, calling `server.use()` to mock my response for a specific request inside my test, but MSW does not return the the response defined with the `use` method, but the one defined in my default handlers given when called `setupServer()`.

For example, I am doing the following:

```js
  it('should call the correct endpoint and return the API response', async () => {
    mockApiResponse({
      endpoint: `/companies/1/api-key`,
      method: RESTMethods.POST,
      response: MOCK_CREATE_COMPANY_API_KEY_API_RESPONSE,
      statusCode: 201,
    })

    const { result, waitFor } = renderHook(() => useCreateCompanyApiKey(1))
    result.current.mutate()
    await waitFor(() => result.current.isSuccess)
    expect(result.current.data).toEqual(MOCK_CREATE_COMPANY_API_KEY_API_RESPONSE)
  })
```

For the record, here's the implementation of my `mockApiResponse` method:

```js
const mockApiResponse = ({
  endpoint = '*',
  method = RESTMethods.GET,
  response = {},
  statusCode = 200,
}: MockApiResponseArgs) => {
  switch (method) {
    case RESTMethods.DELETE:
      server.use(rest.delete(endpoint, (req, res, ctx) => res(ctx.status(statusCode), ctx.json(response))))
      break
    case RESTMethods.PATCH:
      server.use(rest.patch(endpoint, (req, res, ctx) => res(ctx.status(statusCode), ctx.json(response))))
      break
    case RESTMethods.POST:
      server.use(rest.post(endpoint, (req, res, ctx) => res(ctx.status(statusCode), ctx.json(response))))
      break
    case RESTMethods.PUT:
      server.use(rest.put(endpoint, (req, res, ctx) => res(ctx.status(statusCode), ctx.json(response))))
      break
    default:
      server.use(rest.get(endpoint, (req, res, ctx) => res(ctx.status(statusCode), ctx.json(response))))
      break
  }
}
```

And just so you know, my `useCreateCompanyApiKey` hook is a custom hook around the `useMutation` one from `@tanstack/react-query`

With this, code, with Jest, I have the test passing, with vitest, it won't has the response of the request won't be the value of `MOCK_CREATE_COMPANY_API_KEY_API_RESPONSE` ...

If anyone has an idea or has already encountered a similar issue, it can really help me! :)

Comment: Where is `server` defined within your `mockApiResponse` function? It could be using the global instance rather than a local instance. Try passing in `server` as a function argument to see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

It is actually imported from the file where I instanciated it like this:

```typescript
import { server } from 'src/../config/mockServiceWorker/mswServer'